# GPGPU capabilities

Tags: opengl, gpgpu

Is GPGPU a whole set of separate platform that performs different processes on GPU, or it is using OpenGL libraries to achieve the same thing?
In other words, does GPGPU has its own set of libraries, and it is hardware dependent? Or it can be run on any hardware as long as that hardware supports OpenGL? I think I am not sure how GPGPU is different than OpenGL? I know that a byproduct of OpenGL is to do some hefty parallel computations, so you don't really have to only use its graphical capabilities. But how about GPGPU?

Comment: if it helps, in a vague marketing-friendly way of looking at it, opengl could draw "1+1" on your screen and give you a pretty picture. GPGPU would actually calculate "1+1" and give you "2". both can use the underlying gpu to do so, but may do their job using software emulation only.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL GPGPU is hardware independent (rather, between Nvidia and AMD). CUDA is a GPGPU language that is Nvidia only.

GPGPU is different from OpenGL in that, it can preform arbitrary operations that are outside the scope of the OpenGL API. Want to do sparse matrix multiplication via a parallel process? Use OpenCL or CUDA, OpenGL will not provide the ability to build this (or if it can, it would be much more difficult).

GPGPU is separate from OpenGL and DirecX.

Comment: OpenGL 4.3 has Compute shaders which are for GPGPU computations.But , yes , still CUDA and OpenCL are the way to go if massively parallel general computations is needed....

Answer (score 2):

GPGU is a concept, referring to the ability to use GPUs to do arbitrary computations, rather than just drawing pictures.

Nowadays, there are two mechanisms for doing GPGPU. The simplest way is to use an API designed for GPGPU. OpenCL is the cross-platform method. CUDA exists for those willing to limit themselves to NVIDIA's ecosystem. These APIs define C/C++ APIs and special languages for executing code on the GPU, as well as for interfacing with GPU memory (sending data to be processed and reading back results).

The other way is to simply draw "pictures" using a regular rendering API and read the results back. To use this, you have to format your input and output data so that it matches with what a rendering system wants to do.

The latter method is generally avoided with two exceptions. One, if the hardware in question can't support OpenCL/CUDA/etc, you obviously have no choice but to use a rendering API. Or two, if the GPGPU operation is used to *feed* rendering operations. Thinks like frustum culling for instances, particle system computations, and the like. If what you're doing is only going to be used by later rendering operations directly, then it's best to use the rendering API itself. There can be performance penalties associated with inter-operation between OpenCL/CUDA and rendering APIs like OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do some GPGPU stuff using straight OpenGL (by writing custom shaders and using textures to pass data), it is typically more common to do GPGPU using a specialized library like nVidia's CUDA.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand it correctly, you can use OpenCL or CUDA or even OpenGL (which is not the best standard for this purpose) to do GPGPU stuff. Is this correct?

Comment: You can, but you may be limited in what is possible. GPGPU using OpenGL predates a lot of the modern GPGPU APIs -- people have been using shaders for GPGPU computation for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a cross-platform standard API for using 3d acceleration hardware. A "universal language for talking to graphics cards", if you will.

GPGPU is not a standard, as such. It is a bit of an umbrella term, referring to a whole slew of techniques for performing **General Purpose** computing on **GPUs** (hence the name GPGPU).

In the stone ages (before CUDA/OpenCL), you had to jump through hoops to do simple stuff, and even slightly complex stuff was best left to GPU experts. Eg: You could add two arrays by storing them in textures, then do multi-texturing (with OpenGL set up to perform addition of the textures), followed by reading back the rendered texture from a screen-aligned quad.

With the advent of CUDA and OpenCL, you can now write general-purpose code (eg: matrix multiplication), albeit with some modifications to exploit the parallelism in the GPU hardware, and then run it on the GPU without resorting to elaborate OpenGL tricks (like the multi-texture add).

Hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, so is this correct inference to say that GPGPU for achieving such computing techniques uses OpenGL?

Comment: @user2112840: No it isn't. As he said, you don't have to use a rendering API to achieve GP-GPU.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I don't have to use, but I can use. Is this correct? In other words, it is better to use OpenCL or CUDA for GPGPU stuff, but I can also use OpenGL to do GPGPU (even though OpenGL is not meant for this purpose and it mainly a rendering tool), correct?

Comment: Yes, you can still use OpenGL to do GPGPU, the way it was done 10 years ago. Knock yourself out: http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/rtongfx/rtongfx.pdf